# How to signout from an Azure Application?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service

I have created a Azure AD application and a Web App. The Azure AD Application uses AAD Authentication. This works well. When I go to my URL and I am not authenticated, I have to enter my credentials. When I enter my credentials, I am forwarded to my application.

But then comes the problem. How do I sign out. I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592787/owin-authentication-signout-doesnt-remove-cookies) and I wanted to implement option 2: not signing out using code, but using links Azure AD provides. The point is, I have no clue where to configure this. He states

> Add some specific links for logging in and logging out

But where? Where in Azure and in which portal (new or old) can I configure this? He also provided a link with a sample, but I don't understand this sample (I kind of new to Azure).

Answer (score 19):

What you can do is construct a sign out URI in your application and when the user clicks on the `Logout` link or button, you redirect your users to that URI.

The format of a sign out URI is:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={1}
```

Where `{0}` is the Tenant Id or the Azure AD name (`something.onmicrosoft.com`) and `{1}` is the link to your application where a user will be redirected back after the sign out process is complete at Azure AD end.

Comment: I found that when I .auth/logout, it logs me out everywhere so that .auth/me?provider=aad no longer works.

Answer (score 7):

I finally found why I couldn't get the provided example to work which I mentioned in my start post: the setting `WEBSITE_AUTH_LOGOUT_PATH` is deprecated and you can now call `/.auth/logout` to log out.

Found it on [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/17661111-c2d9-41ac-ab5b-df1cf7190585/websiteauthlogoutpath-since-novemeber-2015?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

Comment: I guess you may still have to delete the browser cookies. For me it redirects to my home page but successfully logs user in.

Comment: Redirecting to /.auth/logout will also automatically delete the session cookies. Note that If you want to redirect to a custom page after the logout completes, you can use something like /.auth/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=/mylogoutpage.html (replace /mylogoutpage.html to any path you want).

Comment: @ChrisGillum Thank you for the custom 'after logout page'. Didn't know about that. But where did you found this info? Where is this documented?

Comment: Full disclosure - I am the developer of this feature so I know it from memory. :D I'll chat with our doc writers to figure out if we have this properly documented somewhere. There's a good chance we missed it.

Comment: Chris, is there a way to logout from aad without logging out everywhere. I find that if I .auth/logout on one client, it will cause the server to no longer be able to access .auth/me?provider=aad even though the token is good. As soon as another client logins in, then it works again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the URI

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={1}
```

as @Gaurav suggested. But this does not clear the browser cookies. You may have to explicitly delete the cookies from your Request Object:

```
foreach (string cookie in HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys) { HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);}
```

But, there's also one issue with this that Azure AD caches the cookies for some time interval so any request sent using the same cookie from any other source could be authenticated successfully by Azure AD. I'm still trying to figure out how to tackle this.

Hope this helps. Thanks